# How to extract calendar from datepicker?

Tags: html, angular, servicenow

I've found custom and pretty neat [datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-datepicker/v/2.1.23) that I would like to use as it seems very flexible to my requirements, however the only issue I am having is that usually all datepickers that I've seen are based on that you have to click for etc. on text field to open up the calendar.

Is there any simple way to extract just the calendar without having to click on the field? I've looked into its [source code](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker/blob/master/dist/angular-datepicker.js) but did not find much. Anyone had the same "requirement"?

[image: Image of datepciker]

Comment: The docs (not very clearly) seem to suggest setting `datepicker-show` to true and  `datepicker-toggle` to false.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could manually show the calendar so that it's already open once the page loads and also hide the input field.

Reference:
https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker#manually-show-and-hide-datepicker

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working, I thought that it meant something like "hide/show from the form".